# Windows Service to Azure?

Tags: c#, windows-services, azure

I've written a Windows Service in C# that does a whole bunch of background admin tasks on the database.  Now my customer wants to migrate the whole shebang to Azure.  I know next to nothing about Azure, and my customer says you can't run a Windows Service on Azure.  I've googled for this topic and come out with a few very specific case studies of what somebody did to move their Windows Service to Azure, assuming a fairly high level of understanding of how Azure works, but no general articles about whether or not Windows Services can run under Azure, or what to do to adapt them.

I would really like to see a clear answer and explanation to the first question (can you run a Windows Service under Azure?), and if the answer is no, I'd love to find a step-by-step guide for converting a Windows Service to something Azure-compatible.

Thanks!

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Yes you can do that - for a simple walkthrough see http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mwasham/archive/2011/03/30/migrating-a-windows-service-to-windows-azure.aspx

Other links with relevant information:

- [Getting a Service to Run Inside of an Azure Worker Role](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7032934/getting-a-service-to-run-inside-of-an-azure-worker-role/7059424#7059424)
- http://www.codeproject.com/KB/azure/WCFWorkerRole.aspx

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Answer (score 6):

You can run whatever you want, including a Windows Service.

I think you'd be happier converting to a [WorkerRole](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/cloud-services-dotnet-multi-tier-app-storage-4-worker-role-a/), though, which should be very straightforward.

Comment: Too bad you didn't add a refference for a short tutorial or an article like this one: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/joseph_fultz/archive/2010/04/02/migrating-windows-service-to-azure-worker-role-image-conversion-example-using-storage.aspx

Comment: What a weird comment. The accepted answer has several links (more recent than the one you suggest).

Comment: Actually, i don't mean to be a pr**k but the accepted answer is talking about "hosting" a windows service inside a Worker Role while you suggest to "convert" the windows service into a worker role - those two are different approaches and i gotta say that i like yours better. That's exactly why it would have been helpful if you added a refference to a more thorough explenation...

Answer (score 2):

For smaller jobs, you can use Azure's WebJob facility, which runs within a web app (useful if you're doing background tasks on the same data that a front-end site is managing).

There's a nice breakdown here:
https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-create-web-jobs/

WebJobs are pretty easy to get running, but don't have the power of Worker Roles.  See the following for a comparison:
[Worker Role vs Web Job](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25825290/worker-role-vs-web-job)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, no problem, here is another nice and easy to follow example [Get Started with Azure Cloud Services](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/cloud-services-dotnet-get-started/). It (also) clearly shows how to implement the WorkerRole. You can use the WebRole to manage your service.

Answer (score 0):

Here are the steps to install a windows service on Windows Azure running VM with Windows Server 2012 R2:

- start your VM in Windows Azure Console and connect to it with Remote Desktop Connector
- map your storage as a new drive in your VM:

  net use z: \mystorage.file.core.windows.net\endoint /u:myusername verylongkeythatendswith==

Storage key can be found in your Azure Management Console -> Storages -> Manage Access Keys

- copy all the necessary installation files to the mapped storage (copy&paste)
- copy nssm to a local drive (not z: as it uses MAFS file system and that cannot be accessed with low-level windows API commands)
- Create a .bat file with the following entries

> set username=xxx
>   set password=yyy
>   call d:\nssm install "My service"
>   "%programfiles%\PathToService\myservice.exe" "-p 8677"
>       d:\nssm set "My service" ObjectName "%username%" "%password%"
>       sc failure "My service" actions= restart/60000/restart/60000/restart/60000 reset= 240
>       d:\nssm start "My service"

Username and password should be the ones you used to create the VM.

- run the script. The service should be visible in your services list.

Enjoy!

PS : I used [NSSM](http://nssm.cc/download) to simplify the service deployment.

Answer (score 0):

I would use web jobs for this, it's scheduling functionality and easy deployment/config makes this a trivial task. Zip up your .exe and upload it, then set a schedule and you're done.

Answer (score -1):

Yes u can , in the website there are a task web jobs y can create a batch, wsh, powershell(need the azure power shell) or using the web jobs API, rest API, on the other hand we have azure automation is similar but use work flow

Comment: Could you provide some screenshots or better explained examples of how to do this? This would help the asker more.