# Move Windows Service to Windows Azure

Tags: azure, windows-services

I have a windows service (written in c #. Net) that checks an email address every 5 minutes. Depending on the contents of the email and save the downloaded email in a database. Now I would like to move the service to Windows Azure, is this possible? The database is already available in Windows Azure?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use SQL Azure in place of SQL Server and a worker role in place of your NT service. The number one problem you'll have to deal with is allowing for at least two instances of your worker role to run concurrently (that's an SLA requirement).

See answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7794572/57428) for more details.