# An app, not website, for Microsoft Azure platform

Tags: c#, azure

In advance, sorry for stupid question, but all search results in google are off-topic for me.

I want to create a C# application, that will run continuously on an Azure VM. It should NOT be event driven, as it will use different factors (db monitoring, time schedule, overall usage) to decide its activity.

Now, should I just create a console app in VS Express 2013 for Desktop and run it using RDP on VM? Or is there some azure-specific project that I can use (maybe for better integration with management portal)? All I can see and find is web-related (a website, a webjob, a background worker, a webapi), and mine app will not in any way be accessed remotely (it will periodically check db shared with a ASP.NET website)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The corresponding azure type is "Cloud Services / Worker role". They work just as windows services.

So you can basically take all classes from your windows service (except `Service1.cs`) and put them in the new azure project.

The copy all start/stop code from your `Service1.cs` to the corresponding class in your new Cloud service project.

http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/documentation/articles/cloud-services-dotnet-multi-tier-app-storage-4-worker-role-a/

Comment: Thanks! I guess I got lost in all that nomenclature that I assumed Cloud Service is a WebService-like project :)

Answer (score 4):

It is possible. You should create the equivalent of a Windows Service, but then for Azure.

There is a useful question for that already on SO: [Windows Service to Azure?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7794572/windows-service-to-azure)

It has a reference to a full walk though: [Migrating a Windows service to Windows Azure](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mwasham/archive/2011/03/30/migrating-a-windows-service-to-windows-azure.aspx).