# Read email, dump attachment to blob

Tags: asp.net, email, azure

I'm writing an .net 4.5 app to be deployed to Azure.  I'd like to have a worker role which periodically checks an email address for new messages, copies the attachments off any emails, and dumps them to blob storage.

I see lots of stuff on how to send email, but not how to actually monitor an email account and process messages.

EDIT:
The blobs are files which will then be displayed to the user

Comment: Realize that the ASP.Net pipeline is executed per request.  This means that ASP.Net cannot run *scheduled* tasks.  Instead you should write [a different type of Azure application](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7794572/windows-service-to-azure) that can run as you see fit.

Comment: @ErikPhilips, I disagree.  We have several architectures that use worker roles to implement scheduled tasks.  In addition, Azure offers its own scheduler which can call a controller action to run a task on a schedule.  Maybe I'm misunderstanding you?

Comment: @scottndecker - worker roles are not web apps.  What is the point of writing an MVC app if it's not doing anything web related?

Comment: The link I provided talks about Windows Services and WorkerRole.

Comment: @ErikFunkenbusch, agreed on the point of MVC app.  See edits.

Comment: @scottndecker - so the mvc part is doing nothing email related, it's just displaying blobs to the user.  that seems simple enough, what's the problem with that?

Comment: @ErikFunkenbusch, absolutely.  Getting blobs and showing them is cake.  The tough part is creating a worker role that will monitor an email account and pull attachments from emails into blob storage.

Comment: @scottndecker - Then I would suggest that since your real problem has nothing to do with MVC, you de-emphasis that (in fact, remove it entirely) and focus instead on the root of your problem, .net and email processing, perhaps with a azure worker role bent.  As it is, the mvc tags and title just confuse things.

Answer (score 0):

There are two methods you can employ to monitor an email account.  Either

1. poll the account using POP3 or IMAP - slightly yuk
2. use a more proactive approach such as IMAP Idle ([more information](http://www.isode.com/whitepapers/imap-idle.html)) which can receive new message notifications client-side, assuming the mail server supports this.

A quick hunt around NuGet will turn up a variety of libraries that support the above techniques, although to get you started I've found [S22.Imap](https://www.nuget.org/packages/S22.Imap/) more than adequate and has sufficient examples.

Enjoy