# No job functions found. Try making your job classes and methods public

Tags: c#, azure-functions, azure-webjobs, azure-webjobssdk, azure-functions-runtime

First off, I have looked at the other SO posts with the same error message and none seem to resolve my issue. I have tried many permutations and options. My function builds fine but will not run in the CLI, I get the following cryptic error. The MSFT documentation does not seem to have the answers either.

> No job functions found. Try making your job classes and methods public. If you're using binding extensions (e.g. ServiceBus, Timers, etc.) make sure you've called the registration method for the extension(s) in your startup code (e.g. config.UseServiceBus(), config.UseTimers(), etc.).

I am trying to run a timer job and then write a collection of messages to an event hub. What am I missing? I have been fighting this for hours.

**Function:**

```
    [FunctionName("CreateData")]
    public static async Task Run([TimerTrigger("0 */5 * * * *")]TimerInfo myTimer,
        [EventHub("murraytest", Connection = "evingest")] IAsyncCollector<string> myeventhub,
        TraceWriter log)
    {
        await myeventhub.AddAsync("data1");
        await myeventhub.AddAsync("data2");
        await myeventhub.AddAsync("data3");

        log.Info($"COMPLETED: {DateTime.Now}");
    }
```

**local.settings.json:**

```
{
  "IsEncrypted": false,
  "Values": {
    "AzureWebJobsStorage": "UseDevelopmentStorage=true",
    "Eventhub": "UseDevelopmentStorage=true",
    "AzureWebJobsDashboard": "",
    "evingest": "Endpoint=sb://example.servicebus.windows.net/;SharedAccessKeyName=RootManageSharedAccessKey;SharedAccessKey=LtcqBLT5VWjg0dGMdIvxCcEGs8902010Y6y14iGg="

  }
}
```

**Packages**

[image: Nuget]

**function.json** - is missing any eventhub bindings!

```
{
  "generatedBy": "Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions-1.0.0.0",
  "configurationSource": "attributes",
  "bindings": [
    {
      "type": "timerTrigger",
      "schedule": "0 */5 * * * *",
      "useMonitor": true,
      "runOnStartup": false,
      "name": "myTimer"
    }
  ],
  "disabled": false,
  "scriptFile": "..\\bin\\AzFuncs.dll",
  "entryPoint": "AzFuncs.Function1.Run"
}
```

Comment: Do you mind upgrading to the latest Sdk.Functions (1.0.6)?

Comment: First remove ServiceBus reference, then upgrade Sdk, then add it again

Comment: ServiceBus should be `2.1.0-beta4` too

Comment: When you are done, check that `function.json` file is generated in `bin\Debug\net461\CreateData`

Comment: Ok, fixing the assemblies to the correct versions in a new project worked for this error, but I do notice that the functions.json built in the bin is missing eventhub bindings. The function now runs, but no messages produced.

Comment: It's ok, input and output bindings are not put into generated json file. They still work.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

**UPDATE**

My post below is coming up 5 years old.  While it is still relevant, there are other answers here you should "and" together with mine.  (Esp the net 5 FunctionName).

**Original**

Another gotcha I found especially if you are converting from another project or version.

In the VS csproj file, make sure **AzureFunctionsVersion** is present

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
<PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netstandard2.0</TargetFramework>
    <AzureFunctionsVersion>v2</AzureFunctionsVersion>
</PropertyGroup>
...etc
```

the tooling adds this automatically but not added if you are modifying a project where this was missing.  Hope this helps you save the 3 hours it cost me :-).

Answer (score 51):

If you are using Azure Functions in .NET 5 or higher with the out-of-proces execution model you need to replace your `FunctionName` with `Function`, otherwise the function will not be detected.

Before:

```
[FunctionName("CreateData")]
```

After:

```
[Function("CreateData")]
```

Comment: Thanks, this is indeed the correct answer if one is using .NET 5!
Upvoted (I fail to understand why someone down voted this answer, I upvoted)

Comment: Here's the official documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/dotnet-isolated-process-developer-howtos?tabs=browser&pivots=development-environment-vs#rename-the-function

Comment: God damn you saved me hours of madness, thanks!

Comment: Why would they change this?

Comment: What is the Nuget package and the namespace for the FunctionAttribute?

Comment: `Function` attribute is in the namespace `Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker`

Comment: I think the reason this response may have been downvoted is because it is easy to miss the "out-of-proces execution model" reference, and the error message in the original post doesn't indicate in or out of process.

To clarify: [Function] is for out of process and [FunctionName] is the attribute for in process.

I got here because I was looking up the error message in an in-process upgrade to v4 from v3 on Azure recommendation and had this error message when in-process. In this case, the [Function] attribute is a red herring.

Comment: @DavidBridge Did you find a solution to your problem? I am also receiving this error while trying to upgrade the function runtime from 3 to 4 on an in-process function.

Comment: The complete lack of quality in the Function project creation process using latest VS 2022 is unbelievable. Azure Functions team, is anyone there paying attention?

Comment: No clear documentation, all the ones from Microsoft are outdated. No nice sample or template found in internet for Azure Webjobs!

Comment: You are transforming WebJob to an Isolated Azure Function (Worker Role) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25825290/worker-role-vs-web-job

Comment: Thanks mate, this worked for me on .NET 6 and function version 4 

Comment: question is using Azurite is it in our out process?

Answer (score 28):

As addition to the existing answers: We had this issue when upgrading from .net 6 in-process mode to .net 8 with dotnet-isolated mode.

So the nugets depencencies changed from `Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.*` ([in-process bindings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-develop-vs?tabs=in-process#add-bindings)) to `Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker` ([isolated bindings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/dotnet-isolated-process-guide#core-packages)). Also we renamed `[FunctionName("MyFunction")]` to `[Function("MyFunction")]`.

So in the `local.settings.json` the `FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME` was still the old value of `dotnet`, but the correct value had to be:

```json
{
  "IsEncrypted": false,
  "Values": {
    "AzureWebJobsStorage": "UseDevelopmentStorage=true",
    "FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME": "dotnet-isolated",
    // ...
  }
}
```

Comment: Perfect! Was missing the FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME entry. Putting it in made all the difference.

Comment: GOLD.....THIS ANSWER IS GOLD!

Comment: I ran the .NET Upgrade Assistant tool on my function to upgrade from .NET 6 to .NET 7. It correctly upgraded *almost* everything, but missed this!

Answer (score 17):

I randomly had this issue but it only affected the functions in one class. Turned out I just needed to run a `dotnet clean` first.

Comment: Thanks for this! I ran into this issue after I added a nested setting to my configuration. I confirmed that this is what broke the function app, but if I undid the change and put the configuration back to the default... I would still get this error. It was only after running a dotnet clean that the error went away.

Answer (score 10):

My issue was different from the other answers: the `local.settings.json` was explicitly included in the `.gitignore` definition.  As such the file was not included in a clone and the local build couldn't understand which was the correct runtime to use.

I pulled the default `local.settings.json` from a sample project to restore the file.

Comment: Thanks! That thing was holding me back too.

Answer (score 7):

In my case I was simply running the command from an actual function directory. You should run it from the root of the functions project instead!

Answer (score 6):

You should upgrade to the latest `Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions` (`1.0.6` as of today) and `Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Service.Bus` (`2.1.0-beta4` if running on full framework). You might need to remove the ServiceBus reference first in order to upgrade SDK.

The `Microsoft.Azure.Eventhubs` package also needs to be removed. All relevant types etc are in `Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Service.Bus`

Also remember to check "Include prerelease" in the package manager in order to find `2.1.0-beta4`.

Answer (score 4):

In my case, the clue was this message at the start of the console output:

```
Can't determine project language from files. Please use one of [--csharp, --javascript, --typescript, --java, --python, --powershell]
```

Adding the `--csharp` argument did the trick.

Comment: I had the same problem. Fixed it by adding FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME as a setting in my local.settings.json. Acceptable values can be found [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-app-settings#functions_worker_runtime)

Answer (score 4):

This happened to me after a nuget upgrade for `Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Sdk` to `1.16.2` (also experienced by a user in this SO thread above, https://stackoverflow.com/a/77440385/12482573).

I found an open issue here (https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-dotnet-worker/issues/2070) and a workaround that is working for me and a couple of people in the issue thread.

The workaround, according to the comments in the issue posted above, is to add the following to your csproj `PropertyGroup`:

`<FunctionsEnableWorkerIndexing>False</FunctionsEnableWorkerIndexing>`.

Comment: Seems like this issue is still occurring. I had to do this after upgrading all my packages.

Answer (score 2):

Had this error on my local machine out of the blue, after nuget update of an shared assembly. The same function still worked on a build server. It looks like something lingering from past build outputs/packages caused this.

**My Setup:**

- .NET 7, out of process.
- VS.NET 2022
- Core Tools Version:       4.0.5085 Commit hash: N/A  (32-bit)
- Function Runtime Version: 4.16.4.20366

**I had to do the following to get rid of the issue:**

- Stop VS.NET
- Delete bin folders
- Delete obj folders
- Clear nuget cache in C:\Users<username>.nuget
- Restart VS.NET, build and run

Answer (score 1):

In my case (v3 on net core 3.1) it was a weird case that somehow this was removed from csproj file.

```
<None Update="local.settings.json">
  <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
  <CopyToPublishDirectory>Never</CopyToPublishDirectory>
</None>
```

Answer (score 1):

I got the error mentioned in the question in Rider when I tried to run localy azure function. I tried to run proejct in Visual Studio and I got another error during the build:

> A project with an Output Type of Class Library can not be started directly.

It turned out that I removed at some point from csproj package reference:

```
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions" Version="4.1.3" />
```

After adding it to csproj I am able to run azure function.

Answer (score 1):

so for me it worked when i startet the function with:
"func start --csharp"

edit: after the first time starting the function with the func start --csharp command i can now start it normal with func start

Answer (score 1):

i had this problem recently and took me 2 days to found out that i only need the latest version of  azure functions core tools.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

This started happening after upgrading to Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Sdk 1.16.0. A downgrade to 1.15.1 solved the issue.

See: https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-dotnet-worker/issues/2029

Answer (score 0):

I appreciate the other answers here. But in my case none of them worked on **VS Code**.

I am still trying to use .NET core SDK version of 2.1 and had to use all old version of dependencies for my Azure function.

Even after everything seeming right, I was still unable to run the function locally. Turns out, there is a small step to be taken:

1. First, publish your project `dotnet publish`
2. The published stuff should be in `bin/Debug/netstandard2.0` . Just get inside this folder and run your function:

   ```
   cd bin/Debug/netstandard2.0  # I was using netstandard2.0 framework
   func start --build # You can add --verbose flag for more detailed outputs
   ```

Voila! That's it. Just to be clear, here are my versions:

- .NET core SDK version: 2.1.810
- Azure CLI version: 2.12.0
- Azure Function version: v2
- Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions: 1.0.37

Answer (score 0):

in my scenario, for **Existing Project**, I missed to give reference in .csproj file after installing azure function setup in windows

here is it

you can run command on VS Code **Func init --force** and Select **Dotnet template** and then delete **.csproj** file which is created automatically.

**local.settings.json**

```
"Values": {
        "AzureWebJobsStorage": "UseDevelopmentStorage=false",
        "FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME": "dotnet"
    }
```

**.csproj file**

```
<ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions" Version="3.0.11" />
  </ItemGroup>
```

I hope someone helps out there if you are using like me visual studio code.

Comment: That was it, thank you. I managed to delete `Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions` from the project :(

Answer (score 0):

It happened to me when I changed the name of the project and some other refactoring. It was working on that machine after the change, but interesting enough when I switch to a different machine, I got this error - even if it's the same code.

The solution was for me basically creating a random new azure function and running again. All my functions appeared on the cli on the next run.

Answer (score 0):

I was running "func start" from the wrong folder. Make sure you're running it from the root folder of the azure function. This should be true for any language (I'm using python)

Answer (score 0):

I got the error

> no job functions found

when my firewall was blocking the azure functions program from connecting to the internet.

Answer (score 0):

I found this error when I use FunctionName like this:

```
 [FunctionName("Example/signup")]
```

I removed "/" in FunctionName and resolved it.

Answer (score 0):

After having upgraded a lot of packages - amongst others the one that triggered the change from [FunctionName("CreateData")] to [Function("CreateData")], I needed to delete the bin and obj folder before the functions were discovered again.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue after I changed the project from .Net Core to .Net 6.0 Framework.
In the end I created a new project from scratch and copied the code across.

Answer (score 0):

I got this error during cleanup, when I recreated my project from an existing project. I had originally left out the host.json file.  But I continued to see the message when launching the core tools window.

I deleted the bin and obj folders in the project folder, restarted and this seemed to fix the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I Recently came across this issue and found it to be something else.

For context of my situation i am upgrading a .NET5 Function to .NET6 and it is a 'dotnet-isolated' function that i am working with that is triggered by from serviceBus.

```
        [Function(nameof(XFunction))]        
    public async Task Run([ServiceBusTrigger(QueueName, Connection = "ServiceBusName", IsSessionsEnabled = true)] string? message, FunctionContext context)
```

For me, the fix to this was actually reading some of the documentation a little closer.

(See: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/migrate-version-1-version-4?source=recommendations&tabs=net6-isolated%2Cazure-cli%2Cwindows&pivots=programming-language-csharp)

The key point was: [Relevent Snapsot of docs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dxMOE.png)

The .NET5 function was referencing:

```
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Logging.ApplicationInsights" Version="3.0.33" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script.ExtensionsMetadataGenerator" Version="1.2.3" />
```

As soon as i removed these and re-ran the function it worked as expected.

Hope this saves someone a little time if they are in my shoes now in the future :)

Answer (score -1):

If it's working from `bin/Debug/netcoreapp3.1/` etc this is because you are missing some needed files in the root or missing sections in some files. (eg: host.json)

I managed to fix this by running `func init --force` to restore the initial setup and use git to find the missing sections.

[image]

Answer (score -1):

perhaps try to add

```
<ItemGroup>
        <Using Include="System.Threading.ExecutionContext" ="ExecutionContext" >
</ItemGroup>
```

into your project file, especially if you migrate to dotnet-isolated framework

Comment: Thank you for your interest in contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This question already has quite a few answers—including one that has been extensively validated by the community. Are you certain your approach hasn’t been given previously? **If so, it would be useful to explain how your approach is different, under what circumstances your approach might be preferred, and/or why you think the previous answers aren’t sufficient.** Can you kindly [edit] your answer to offer an explanation?

Answer (score -2):

For some reason, my working project got this below info duplicated in the csproj file, and so ran into this same error while running the AzFunction locally. I removed the extraneous lines and it worked just fine.

```
<ItemGroup>
    <None Include="Function1.cs" />
</ItemGroup>
```