# Azure function local development in VS cannot find function

Tags: c#, visual-studio, azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-functions

I'm currently developing a function app using Microsoft's Azure functions in Visual Studio. I am able to deploy and publish the functions on azure and it seems to run but whenever I try to run a function **local** the *Hosting Environment* is unable to find any *"Jobs"*. I have included a picture below.

It must be stated that I was at some point able to deploy locally but I believe after some updates, I was unable to run my functions

The current version of ***Azure Function and Web Jobs Tools***: 15.0.40424.0

I have tried to use Azure Functions V1 (.NET Frameworks) and Azure Functions V2 (.NET Core) when I create a new project but with unsuccessful results. I have also tried to create a new clean project, reinstall VS and also reset Windows in case of any strange setup.

Am I missing something and do I explicitly need state my functions somewhere such that the *hosting environment* can find them??

**Hosting environment not finding any functions:**

```
[6/20/2018 7:24:37 AM] Host configuration file read:
[6/20/2018 7:24:37 AM] {}
[6/20/2018 7:24:37 AM] Starting Host (HostId=2017noy-1005193785, 
 InstanceId=c8332a19-7eb3-4446-9b3e-4307f20a57bc, Version=2.0.11651.0, 
 ProcessId=15184, AppDomainId=1, Debug=False, ConsecutiveErrors=0, 
 StartupCount=1, FunctionsExtensionVersion=)

[6/20/2018 7:24:38 AM] Generating 0 job function(s)
[6/20/2018 7:24:38 AM] No job functions found. Try making your job classes 
 and methods public. If you're using binding extensions (e.g. ServiceBus, 
 Timers, etc.) make sure you've called the registration method for the 
 extension(s) in your startup code (e.g. config.UseServiceBus(), 
 config.UseTimers(), etc.).
```

**Template Empty HTTPTrigger Function - Function1.cs:**

```
using System.IO;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.Http;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

namespace FunctionApp1
{
    public static class Function1
    {
        [FunctionName("Function1")]
        public static IActionResult 
        Run([HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "get", "post", Route = 
            null)]HttpRequest req, TraceWriter log)
        {
            log.Info("C# HTTP trigger function processed a request.");
            string name = req.Query["name"];

            string requestBody = new StreamReader(req.Body).ReadToEnd();
            dynamic data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(requestBody);
            name = name ?? data?.name;

            return name != null
                ? (ActionResult)new OkObjectResult($"Hello, {name}")
                : new BadRequestObjectResult("Please pass a name on the query 
                                            string or in the request body");
        }
    }
}
```

**CSPROJ File**

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netstandard2.0</TargetFramework>
    <AzureFunctionsVersion>v2</AzureFunctionsVersion>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions" Version="1.0.13" 
/>
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <None Update="host.json">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </None>
    <None Update="local.settings.json">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
      <CopyToPublishDirectory>Never</CopyToPublishDirectory>
    </None>
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

**local.settings.json**

```
{
    "IsEncrypted": false,
    "Values": {
        "AzureWebJobsStorage": "UseDevelopmentStorage=true",
        "AzureWebJobsDashboard": "UseDevelopmentStorage=true"
    }
}
```

Comment: can you share your code please ?

Comment: Please avoid screenshots for text and code. Use markdown instead.

Comment: can you share your dependencies in your csproj? in particular `Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions` version

Comment: did you see this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47682760/no-job-functions-found-try-making-your-job-classes-and-methods-public

Comment: @ahmelsayed, thanks for your reply I have included my csproj above!

Comment: @Prawin, yes I did take a look at it and it did not resolve my issue. However, it seems like the OP is using an older version of .NET.Sdk.Functions (1.0.6). What I also notice is he a function.json file in his project, which don't. Is this file required or is it deprecated with my .NET.Sdk.Functions version (1.0.13)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `function.json` file is generated after VS build. Check whether it's in a folder named after your function, under `~\bin\Debug\netstandard2.0` folder.

[image]

If you don't see the folder like `Function1`(containing `function.json` inside), you may have met the same problem my colleague has.

Didn't find the rout cause, VS just failed to generate `function.json` on my colleagues's computer, but on my side things works fine(VS and Azure Function and Web Jobs Tools has the same version).

The workaround we found is to downgrade `Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions` to `1.0.12`.

Just for your reference, we have also tried upgrading `Azure Function and Web Jobs Tools` and delete `Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions` in `C:\Users\UserName\.nuget\packages\microsoft.net.sdk.functions\1.0.13` and install this package again.

**Update**

Upgrade `Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions` to latest version of `1.0.14` also works on our side.

Comment: Thanks, downgrading solved the issue but I still wonder why this is the case?

Comment: @DennisThinhTanNguyen Not familiar with msbuild, guess the targets file(used to generate function.json) for function sdk `1.0.13` is broken or VS fails to resolve it due to some reason. And new version `1.0.14` is available,  upgrade may also be helpful.

Answer (score 2):

I had a same issue but I have downgrade  `Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions` from version 3.0.11 to 3.0.10 and then start a program and it has shown all my functions in the console application once the program successfully runs I have upgraded to the previous function 3.0.11 it worked.

Comment: After trying every other trick on the book, my issue was solved by your answer! Thanks man!