# Azure WebJobs - No job functions found

Tags: .net, azure, azure-functions, azure-webjobs, .net-5

I'm trying to run an Azure Functions project (v3) using .NET 5 however I get the error that no job functions are found. The exact error is this:

> No job functions found. Try making your job classes and methods public.
> If you're using binding extensions (e.g. Azure Storage, ServiceBus,
> Timers, etc.) make sure you've called the registration method for the
> extension(s) in your startup code (e.g. builder.AddAzureStorage(),
> builder.AddServiceBus(), builder.AddTimers(), etc.).

I have a `program.cs` file which looks like this:

```cs
class Program
{
    static Task Main(string[] args)
    {
        var host = new HostBuilder()
            .ConfigureWebJobs(builder =>
            {
                builder.AddTimers();
                builder.AddAzureStorage();
            })
            .ConfigureLogging((context, b) =>
            {
                b.SetMinimumLevel(LogLevel.Debug);
                b.AddConsole();
            })
            .Build();

        return host.RunAsync();
    }
}
```

And I added a timer triggered function looking like this:

```cs
public class CleanUp
{
    [FunctionName(nameof(CleanUp))]
    public static void CleanUpWebJob([TimerTrigger("0 */1 * * * *")] TimerInfo myTimer,
        ILogger log) // every one minute
    {
        if (myTimer.IsPastDue)
        {
            log.LogInformation("Timer is running late!");
        }
        log.LogInformation($"C# Timer trigger function executed at: {DateTime.Now}");
    }
}
```

Obviously I also changed my project file so it runs the v3 correctly. This works fine, I can run the project and see a console window. It's just that the web job is not discovered.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked if the AzureFunctionsVersion is present in the csproj file ( assuming it has been developed from VS)

Also is the working directory/ folder structure correctly set?

For reference,

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/azure/en-US/ed2954e5-04ee-47e7-bbc6-3cf747d5c30d/no-job-functions-found-try-making-your-job-classes-and-methods-public-if-youre-using-binding?forum=AzureFunctions

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-reference#folder-structure

https://github.com/Azure/Azure-Functions/issues/928#issuecomment-502318109

[No job functions found. Try making your job classes and methods public](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47682760/no-job-functions-found-try-making-your-job-classes-and-methods-public)

Comment: Nope, still the same. Started a new project on .NET Core 3.1 and I will share this repo with the product team