# Azure Functions with dependance injection trough constructor don't find job functions

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, azure-functions, .net-5

I've created an Azure Function version 3 using .NET 5 and dependency injection trough the constructor of the class. See dummy code below:

```cs
public class MyAzureFunction
{
    private readonly IMyRepository _myRepository;

    public MyAzureFunction(IMyRepository myRepository) 
    {
        _myRepository = myRepository;
    }

    [Function("MyAzureFunction")]
    public async Task Run([TimerTrigger("0 */15 * * * *")] TimerInfo myTimer, FunctionContext context)
    {
        ILogger logger = context.GetLogger("MyAzureFunction");
        logger.LogInformation($"C# Timer trigger function executed at: {DateTime.Now}");

        List<object> result = await _myRepository.GetAllAsync();

        // Keep going...
    }
}
```

Inside the `Startup` class the scopes are added.

```cs
[assembly: FunctionsStartup(typeof(MyNamespace.Functions.Startup))]
namespace MyNamespace.Functions
{
    public class Startup : FunctionsStartup
    {
        public override void Configure(IFunctionsHostBuilder builder)
        {
            builder.Services
                .AddScoped<IMyRepository, MyRepository>();
        }
    }
}
```

The Program file looks as follow:

```cs
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        IHost host = new HostBuilder()
            .ConfigureFunctionsWorkerDefaults()
            .Build();

        host.Run();
    }
}
```

Inside the `.csproj` file stands this line of code:

```xml
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
    <PropertyGroup>
        <TargetFramework>net5.0</TargetFramework>
        <AzureFunctionsVersion>v3</AzureFunctionsVersion>
        <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    </PropertyGroup>
    <ItemGroup>
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Extensions" Version="1.1.0" />
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Extensions.Timer" Version="4.1.0" />
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Sdk" Version="1.3.0" />
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker" Version="1.6.0" />
    </ItemGroup>
    <!-- Skiped some lines -->
</Project>
```

The problem is when I want to run the Azure Function. I've got this warning:

> No job functions found. Try making your job classes and methods public. If you're using binding extensions *(e.g. Azure Storage, ServiceBus, Timers, etc.)* make sure you've called the registration method for the extension(s) in your startup code *(e.g. `builder.AddAzureStorage()`, `builder.AddServiceBus()`, `builder.AddTimers()`, etc.)*.

I've tried next things:

1. I've added `builder.AddTimers()` inside the `Startup` class but `IFunctionsHostBuilder` contains no definition for it. Even if I add [`Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Extensions.Timer`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Extensions.Timer).
2. Making everything static inside `MyAzureFunction` but don't work because the static constructors can't contain parameters.
3. Also `builder.Services.AddTimers()` *(like in [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-dotnet-dependency-injection#register-services))* is not defined.

My question is now how could I use dependency injection using Azure Functions and .NET 5 using the constructor.

Comment: *I've added builder.AddTimers() inside the Startup class but IFunctionsHostBuilder contains no definition for it.* Then you're missing an assembly reference or NuGet package. Did you try to locate and install the appropriate package?

Comment: @DanielMann: Well, I've added [`Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Extensions.Timer`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Extensions.Timer/4.1.0?_src=template) but same problem.

Comment: @H.Pauwelyn You are using dotnet-isolated version and dependency work differently over there and I have provided my answer. It must work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Program.cs do following things. ( Make sure you add refence for namespace)

```
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;

namespace FunctionApp2
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main()
        {
            var host = new HostBuilder()
                .ConfigureServices(services =>
                {
                    services.AddScoped<IMyRepository, MyRepository>();
                })
                .ConfigureFunctionsWorkerDefaults()
                .Build();

            host.Run();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You have to use your own namespace instead of FunctionApp2 but otherthing will work.

Comment: No, it don't work even if I commented the `Startup` class... I've the same message as inside the question.

Comment: I am not facing any issue and it is working. For your help I have uploaded to github repo and that is working version and it calls every minute. 
https://github.com/jp1482/TimerFunctionAppDotnetIsolated

Comment: The link you've added goes to a 404 page.

Comment: @H.Pauwelyn It was private and now I have made it public.

Comment: Yes that is working. Maby it's a dependancy of the dependancy that gives the error. I'll search for it. It's a +1 from me ☺.

Answer (score 2):

You need to add packages:

- `Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Extensions`
- `Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker`
- `Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Sdk`

Then make sure the previous packages for .NET Core 3 are removed.

Comment: They were already installed in the project but didn't solve the problem. I've updated my question.

Comment: Regarding the 'No job functions found. Try making your job classes and methods public' issue, maybe can refer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47682760/no-job-functions-found-try-making-your-job-classes-and-methods-public.

I think last time encountered this issue too locally and updated the  azure-functions-core-tools.

Comment: Also just to double check the `<ItemGroup>
    <None Update="host.json">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </None>
    <None Update="local.settings.json">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
      <CopyToPublishDirectory>Never</CopyToPublishDirectory>
    </None>
  </ItemGroup>` present in your csproj file right