# Reuse the dependencies of ABP Framework for an Azure Function

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, azure-functions, .net-5, abp

I'm extending a ABP Commercial application with an isolated Azure Function with .NET 5 and want to inject data from the ABP Framework itself.

This is my code:

```cs
public class MyAzureFunction
{
    private readonly IMyRepository _myRepository;

    public MyAzureFunction(IMyRepository myRepository) 
    {
        _myRepository = myRepository;
    }

    [Function("MyAzureFunction")]
    public async Task Run([TimerTrigger("0 */15 * * * *")] TimerInfo myTimer, FunctionContext context)
    {
        ILogger logger = context.GetLogger("MyAzureFunction");
        logger.LogInformation($"C# Timer trigger function executed at: {DateTime.Now}");

        List<object> result = await _myRepository.GetAllAsync();

        // Keep going...
    }
}
```

Here is the code from my `Program` class of the Azure Function project:

```cs
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        IHost host = new HostBuilder()
            .ConfigureServices(services =>
            {
                services
                    .AddDbContext<MyAppDbContext>(OptionsAction, ServiceLifetime.Transient);
                    // `MyAppDbContext` inherits from `AbpDbContext<MyAppDbContext>` and implements 
                    // `IIdentityProDbContext` and `ISaasDbContext`.

                services
                    .AddScoped<IDbContextProvider<MyDbContext>, UnitOfWorkDbContextProvider<MyDbContext>>() // added on 2021-11-05
                    .AddScoped<IMyRepository, MyRepository>();
            })
            .ConfigureFunctionsWorkerDefaults()
            .Build();

        host.Run();
    }

    private static void OptionsAction(DbContextOptionsBuilder options)
    {
        options.UseSqlServer(
            Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("DatabaseConnectionString"), 
            (optionActions) => 
            {
                optionActions.EnableRetryOnFailure(5, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10), null);
                optionActions.CommandTimeout(10);
            }
        );
    }
}
```

The `MyRepository` class inherits from `EfCoreRepository<MyAppDbContext, Foo, Guid>`:

```cs
public class MyRepository : EfCoreRepository<MyAppDbContext, Foo, Guid>, IMyRepository
{
    public ExternalSourceRepository(IDbContextProvider<MyAppDbContext> dbContextProvider) : base(dbContextProvider)
    { }

    public class Task<List<Foo>> GetAllAsync() 
    {
        // Logic here.
    }
}
```

---

The problem is when I run the function.

> System.InvalidOperationException: unable to resolve service for type `Volo.Abp.EntityFrameworkCore.IDbContextProvider<MyNamespace.EntityFrameworkCore.MyAppDbContext>` while attempting to activate `MyNamespace.Foos.MyRepository`.

Is there a way to reuse the dependencies from the ABP framework itself?

I've also tried to create another declaration of `IMyRepository` that doesn't inherit from `EfCoreRepository<MyAppDbContext, Foo, Guid>` but the problem here is that I can't access thing the type of `ExtraPropertyDictionary` object.

```cs
public class MyRepository : IMyRepository
{
    private readonly MyAppDbContext _myAppDbContext;

    public ExternalSourceRepository(MyAppDbContext myAppDbContext)
    {
        _myAppDbContext = myAppDbContext;
    }

    public class Task<List<Foo>> GetAllAsync() 
    {
        // Logic here.
    }
}
```

**Update 2021-11-05**: I've also tried to register `IDbContextProvider<MyDbContext>` as `UnitOfWorkDbContextProvider<MyDbContext>`, but then I've got this exception:

> System.InvalidOperationException: unable to resolve service for type `Volo.Abp.Uow.IUnitOfWorkManager` while attempting to activate `Volo.Abp.Uow.EntityFrameworkCore.UnitOfWorkDbContextProvider<MyNamespace.EntityFrameworkCore.MyDbContext>`.

Could it work if all the dependencies of the dependencies are registered, but what are they and how could it be done?

**Side note:** This question continues on my previous one [Azure Functions with dependency injection through constructor don't find job functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69827227/azure-functions-with-dependance-injection-trough-constructor-dont-find-job-func).

Comment: But where do you register `IDbContextProvider` with the service collection in `Program`

Comment: @Nkosi: Good question, did it nowhere. I've updated my question.

Comment: Some interesting reading [here](https://aspnetboilerplate.com/Pages/Documents/Entity-Framework-Core).  Looks like you are not calling one of the extensions needed to add the required dependencies

Comment: Try using `AddAbpDbContext` instead and see if it adds the required dependencies

Comment: I am facing the same issue, was this ever resolved?

Comment: @DaniMazahreh nope never did...