# Retrieving changesets form a work item programmatically

Tags: c#, azure-devops, wiql

I need to try retrieve a list of changesets that are linked to certain work items and display info on them in the program. But I'm having a lot of trouble figuring it out.

I have been searching the internet extensively for 4 days and have come up empty handed. Is doing this even possible?

I have already tried using wiql http client but it seems to only be able to return work item information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [Get Work Item](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/wit/work-items/get-work-item?view=azure-devops-rest-7.0&tabs=HTTP) with `$expand=relations`. In this case, you receive all relations including changesets. Example:

[image]

Comment: so i have figured out that part just now, but my problem now is that i need to be able to filter out the relations so its just changesets and then store their ID's and dates and comments in a class list

Answer (score 0):

You can reference bellow sample to do that programmatically.

**C# sample** for your reference to retrieve a list of changesets that are linked to a specific work item.

```
using System;
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.WebApi;
using Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.WebApi;
using Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.WebApi.Models;
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Common;

namespace ConsoleApp
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Uri accountUri = new Uri("https://dev.azure.com/{organization}");                 
            String personalAccessToken = "PAT-Here";              
            int workItemId = 227;   // ID of a work item

            // Create a connection to the account
            VssConnection connection = new VssConnection(accountUri, new VssBasicCredential(string.Empty, personalAccessToken));

            // Get an instance of the work item tracking client
            WorkItemTrackingHttpClient witClient = connection.GetClient<WorkItemTrackingHttpClient>();

            WorkItemTrackingHttpClient workItemTrackingClient = connection.GetClient<WorkItemTrackingHttpClient>();

            WorkItem workitem = workItemTrackingClient.GetWorkItemAsync(workItemId, expand: WorkItemExpand.Relations).Result;

            Console.WriteLine(workitem.Id);

            Console.WriteLine("Relations with changesets associated:");
            foreach (var relation in workitem.Relations)
            {

                if (relation.Rel == "ArtifactLink")
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(relation.Url);
                }
            }
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

**PowerShell script** calling the [Get Work Item](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/wit/work-items/get-work-item?view=azure-devops-rest-7.0&tabs=HTTP) REST API to retrieve a list of changesets that are linked to a specific work item.

```
Param(
   [string]$orgurl = "https://dev.azure.com/{organization}", 
   [string]$project = "ProjectName",
   [string]$workitemid = "227",
   [string]$user = "",
   [string]$token = "PAT-Here"
)

# Base64-encodes the Personal Access Token (PAT) appropriately
$base64AuthInfo = [Convert]::ToBase64String([Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(("{0}:{1}" -f $user,$token)))

#Get workitem relateions
$baseUrl = "$orgurl/$project/_apis/wit/workitems/$($workitemid)?"+"$"+"expand=all"          
$response = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $baseUrl -Method Get -Headers @{Authorization=("Basic {0}" -f $base64AuthInfo)}

#Get changesets
$changesets = $response.relations | where {$_.rel -eq 'ArtifactLink' -and $_.attributes.name -eq "Fixed in Changeset"}

if($changesets){
    
    $changesets | select @{N="ChangesetID";E={$_.attributes.comment}}, @{N="CreatedDat";E={$_.attributes.resourceCreatedDate}}, url
}
else {
  Write-Host "No changeset associated to work item $workitemid ."
}
```

[image]

Comment: I tried to run this code as is (of course with my login info and my work item id), and it says i have no job functions found. I'm not sure why

Comment: @LukeClark Not sure what job functions you mentioned. What about running the PowerShell script?  Anyway, check if this hleps : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47682760/no-job-functions-found-try-making-your-job-classes-and-methods-public

Comment: i got that error message when i ran the powershell script. i also looked at that thread and it didnt help my problem

Comment: @LukeClark How did you run the PowerShell script? No jobs involved in the script. Just try to past the script and run it in Windows PowerShell ISE to see if it works.

Comment: I did exactly that and it just doesnt want to work

Comment: @LukeClark That doesn't make sense. Can you please share the screenshot running the script with error?